# Not able to get the model from the multi select plugin

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am using the plugin for my project present in the below link.
http://plnkr.co/edit/cpKHh6kWuV2Zcp7cTD20?p=preview.In the plugin in the script.js class I am trying the print the modal.I am using console to check whether the selected items are dispalyed or not.Because I want to get that elements and send to back end. I am getting undefined error in my console.

```
script.js
angular.module('app', ['ionic','angular.filter'])

.controller('MainController', function($scope) {
$scope.selectable = //items are stored

$scope.parseMulti = function(items){
console.log($scope.multi1)
if(items){
  return items.map(function(item){ return item.fname + ' ' +item.lname;        }).join(', ');
}
};

});
```

Can you someone help me how to get that model.

Comment: I don't have a real solution, but if you debug into $scope.parseMulti you see that this function is called with a child scope of $scope as 'this'. That means you can't easily acces the values of $scope.multi1. But if you just remove the console.log it works as I think you want it to work; it displays the selected items.

Comment: I would suggest you try to figure out, why parseMulti is called with the child scope as 'this'. Seems to be the root of the problem.